# Можно ли создать экземпляр интерфейса в Java?

Tags: java, ооп, классы, интерфейс

Можно ли непосредственно создать экземпляр интерфейса в `Java`, и если да, то для чего это нужно?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Экземпляр интерфейса сделать нельзя. И это не нужно.

В интерфейсе прописаны (причем без тела, только сигнатурами) методы, которые *должны* быть в таких классах, которые реализуют (*implements*) данный интерфейс.

Интерфейс - это *контракт*, "обязательство". Методы в нем не выписываются. Поэтому логично, что экземпляров ему не надо.

Для наглядности вот пример интерфейса с сайта geeksforgeeks:

```
interface Vehicle { 
    // все методы абстрактные
    void changeGear(int a); 
    void speedUp(int a); 
    void applyBrakes(int a); 
}
```

Все, это весь интерфейс. В нем всего три строки, сигнатуры методов без тел.

Answer (score 4):

Можно создать *объект [анонимного класса](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)*, имплементирующего интерфейс:

> Анонимные классы позволяют сделать код более лаконичным. Они позволяют одновременно объявлять класс и создавать его экземпляр. Они похожи на обычные классы, за исключением того, что у них нет названия. Используйте их, если вам нужно использовать объект класса только один раз.

Например, есть интерфейс [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html). Чтобы создать новый поток и запустить его, можно сначала (для наглядности) имплементировать этот интерфейс в некоем классе:

```
public class HelloWorld implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

Затем создать объект этого класса и передать его в конструктор [`Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread(java.lang.Runnable)):

```java
Thread thread = new Thread(new HelloWorld());
thread.start(); // Hello world
```

---

Можно проще - создать объект анонимного класса:

```java
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
});
thread.start(); // Hello world
```

---

И еще проще:

```java
new Thread(() -> System.out.println("Hello world")).start(); // Hello world
```

---

<sup>См. дополнительно: [«Can we create an instance of an interface in Java?»](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4587392/11141611)</sup>

<sup>В `Java8` в интерфейсах появились методы по умолчанию: [Default Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html).</sup>